# How can i return null in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that recieves a list of pairs (e.g. `[(3,'a'),(7,'d'),(1,'c')]`) and a key (e.g. `3`) and returns the value for that key (in this example `'a'`).

The function I've written works fine if the key exists but if i try to return `null` when i did not find a key that matches - I get an error.

the function is :

```
lookup1 k lst = lookupH1 k lst
    where
        lookupH1 k lst 
            | ((length lst) == 0) = null   -- this is the problematic line
            | ((fst (head lst)) == k )= snd (head lst)
            | otherwise = lookupH1 k (tail (lst))
```

what can I do to solve this?

Comment: It's time to start using [`Maybe`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe) and pattern matching: `(length lst) == 0` -> `[]`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response zerkms but your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: What's the point of `lookupH1`? Why not just define `lookup1` directly?

Comment: Historical reasons :) i tried sometime different on that start

Comment: @GiladBaruchian That's actually good practice, it scopes k at the top level, no reason to recurse and continuously pass k around as it stays static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's usually best to first stub out your types and then let the compiler guide you.

In this case, it looks like the signature you are looking at right now is:

```
lookup1 :: Int -> [(Int,Char)] -> Char
```

However, Haskell doesn't have a null that can replace the Char as the return type. Therefore, it's common practice to use Maybe instead. The new type signature would then be.

```
lookup1 :: Int -> [(Int,Char)] -> Maybe Char
```

This would mean that upon finding the value v, you would yield "Just v" and in the case where you don't, it would yield "Nothing".

I hope I'm not giving away too much, but this is a slightly simpler version of your function using pattern matching.

```
lookup1 :: Int -> [(Int,Char)] -> Maybe Char                                    
lookup1 k lst = lookupH1 lst                                                    
    where                                                                       
      lookupH1 [] = Nothing                                                     
      lookupH1 ((k',v):lst')                                                    
        | k == k' = Just v                                                      
        | otherwise = lookupH1 lst'
```

Answer (score 2):

`null` is a function that takes a list and tells you whether or not the list is empty. Since your result is not supposed to be a function, using `null` as your result is a type error.

There is no such thing as a null pointer or null reference in Haskell. If a function has, say, the result type `Char` and the function terminates successfully (i.e. it does not loop forever or throw an exception), the result of calling that function will always be a `Char` value and there is no magical `null` entity that's somehow a value of every type.

So you have two options: Either you throw an exception when the key is not found or (and this is the better option) you change the result type of your function to `Maybe v` rather than `v`.

The type `Maybe t` in Haskell has two possible values: `Just x` where `x` is of type `t` or `Nothing`. So for your (Int, Char) list, your lookup function can return `Just v` when it finds a value for the given key or `Nothing` when it does not, and the user of your function can then pattern match on the result to find out whether a value was found or not and to get at the value if it was found.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Prelude [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function: it returns the type `Maybe b`. Specifically, it returns `Just x` if `x` is the value associated with the key, and `Nothing` if the key isn't found.